Stark effect for $n=2$ level
I have troubles grasping something about the Stark effect and more generally speaking degenerated perturbation theory.
In non-degenerated perturbation theory, one may find the correction for the $\left|1s\right>$ state and energy.
However, in the degenerated case it seems as though we can only treat the whole $n=2$ level, for example, and not individual eigenstates. I understand where it comes from mathematically, as we need to find the good basis that diagonalizes the perturbation in the degenerated subspace and by doing so we find that this basis is (for an homogeneous field along the $z$ axis) (The zeros denote the fact that these kets are eigenkets of the unperturbed Hamiltonian):
$$\left|2p_x^0\right>$$
$$\left|2p_y^0\right>$$
$$\left|+W^0\right>=\frac{\left|2s^0\right>+\left|2p_z^0\right>}{\sqrt{2}}$$
$$\left|-W^0\right>=\frac{\left|2s^0\right>-\left|2p_z^0\right>}{\sqrt{2}}$$
My problem lies in the fact that experimentally, one could isolate a $\left|2s^0\right>$ hydrogen atom and then turn an electric field on. In that case, how would one describe, let's say, the corrected eigenstate mathematically (assuming the intensity of the field is small enough)? My impression was that we had to correct the good basis and write the $\left|2s\right>$ as a superposition of the corrected good basis kets so:
$$\left|2s\right>=\sqrt{2}\left(\left|+W\right>+\left|-W\right>\right)$$
I'm a bit confused, and I would appreciate it if someone could enlighten me.

You're exactly right that one would have to re-express the $|2s \rangle$ state in terms of the new 'good eigenbasis'. In the unperturbed case, any set of four linearly independent states given by some linear combination of the states you've provided will be a valid eigenbasis for the unperturbed Hamiltonian. This is because they all have the same energy. This is what makes it degenerate perturbation theory. But as soon as we turn on the electric field, this is no longer the case as the state you have defined by $|+W^{0} \rangle$ will be a slightly less energy state and the state you have defined by $|-W^{0} \rangle$ will be a slightly higher energy state. We therefore have a preference of eigenbasis in the perturbed case which we didn't have before.
So with regard to the thought experiment proposed where you prepare the state $|2s^{0} \rangle$ then perturb the original Hamiltonian with some small electric field, although initially this is an eigenstate of the system, after we apply the electric field it no longer will be. Instead our choice of eigenbasis is now forced such that we have to express $|2s^{0} \rangle$ in terms of $|+W^{0} \rangle$ and $|-W^{0} \rangle$, each of which are still eigenstates of both the unperturbed and perturbed Hamiltonians. Each W state will evolve with a separate phase due to the differences in energy. Also this is slight nitpicking but your normalisation in the final equation should be $\frac {1}{\sqrt {2}}$ rather than just $\sqrt {2}$.
